# Minimizable message box in VB

Tags: excel, vba

I need a Visual Basic form that will allow the user to scroll through an Excel sheet while the form is running so that they can locate the information they need to enter into the form. Currently, the user must look up all the information before running the macro, which is obviously not very user friendly.

In other words, as the program is now, if the user tries to scroll through the Excel sheet (or do anything at all outside of the form), they are not allowed to without first canceling the form.

Is there a way to do this? Seems like this should be a simple thing to resolve, but I'm having trouble finding good VB documentation online.

Comment: set form property "ShowModal" to False

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I wasn't familiar with the term modal.

Answer (score 1):

Message boxes always pause the execution of the program. You'll need to find an alternative, for example by using the status bar instead, which is probably the easiest option. You can use the status bar in excel like this:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Hello world"
```

and

```
Application.StatusBar = variableName & " pounds."
```

and clear it using:

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```